# Тура и ферзь — происхождение названий

Tags: этимология

Ладью и королеву в шахматах профессионалы называют "тура" и "ферзь". А откуда эти названия и почему только у этих фигур (а еще у офицера-слона) по два названия?

Answer (score 17):

Шахматы стали распространяться по миру в двух направлениях: через Персию на восток и через античный мир на запад. Поэтому существуют разночтения в названиях. Восточные названия: Король,Ферзь, Ладья,Слон,Конь,Пешка
Западные названия: Король,Королева,Тура,Офицер,Конь,Пешка
В современной шахматной терминологии употребляются только восточные наименования шахматных фигур. Использование наименований  «королева», «офицер», «тура» и других свидетельствует о дурном вкусе. Настоящий шахматист не употребляет этих и других, подобных им, наименований, чему есть очень простое объяснение.
Во время шахматной партии на соревнованиях игроки ведут протокол, где записываются все ходы. При записи хода приходится указывать фигуру, которой игрок сделал свой полуход . При этом приняты обозначения: Кр - король, Ф - ферзь, С - слон, К - конь, Л - ладья. Пешка никакой буквой не обозначается.Ферзь -  слово персидского происхождения и в оригинале звучит как Фирзин\Фарзин. В Средние века в Европе был переименован в Королеву (Queen), у немцев это Дама(средневековый культ Прекрасной Дамы) Здесь также влияние таких знаменитых королев, как Элеонора Аквитанская и Изабелла Кастильская, которым  тоже было позволено все в рамках мировых шахмат. Во Франции эта девушка ассоцируется с Жанной д' Арк.  Таким образом, в русском языке сохранилось первоначальное название, но русифицированное.

Ладья - это Колесница.  В русском языке слово ладья тоже звучит странно,  ибо корабль не может с такой  скоростью и мощью носиться по волнам,  как это делает колесница в бою , ладья всегда изображается в виде Башни или Замка, как она и называется в Европе (например, Turm - Башня в Германии). Это название произошло от неправильного перевода персидского слова рокх(колесница) на итальянский рокка (крепость). В результате получилась некая бегающая  скоростная крепость:))

Слон не похож на слона вообще - носит епископскую митру. Эта штука наверху фигуры  - символ епископского католического сана:).  В Европе он зовется Епископ - Bishop,  но наш вариант более древний, ибо изначально он как раз звался слоном - в эпоху шахов и тяжелых колесниц были также и боевые слоны:) В Англии,  прежде чем стать Епископом, эта фигура была Лучником Это также является неправильным переводом персидского названия слона - alfil (archer - лучник в англ). В немецком языке название этой фигуры сейчас - Läufer, который можно перевести как Посланник,  Гонец или например адьютант,   а в прямом смысле - бегун, тот кто очень быстро доставляет послания на большом расстоянии - то есть очень быстрая фигура.Отсюда бытовое название Офицер.В Италии  он Знаменосец 
 В румынском языке, эта  фигура зовется  псих:))) Который носится по всей доске как ненормальный:) Во франции - это шут:)) исторически такое разнообразие сложилось из-за того, что персидский слон напоминал европейцам то митру епископа, то шутовской колпак:)
Вот такое разнообразие...

Comment: Вот интересно, это имеет какое-нибудь отношение к русскому языку?  
Про "многабукафф ниасилел" не говорю даже...

Comment: Зато интересно почитать!

Comment: Вообще-то я отвечала на вопрос, почему у фигур по 2 названия, но автора удовлетворил, видимо,Ваш, в котором не было ответа.Я нисколько не возражаю. Пусть почитают люди, которые осилят  "многабукафф ".

Comment: С удовольствием "многабукафф асилел"

Comment: Интересный ответ! +1

>у немцев это Дама(средневековый культ Прекрасной Дамы)
И у испанцев *Dama*. А у итальянцев *Donna*.

Comment: >почему у фигур по 2 названия   

Больше. Но только одно неправильное. Думаю, исчерпывающе. 

Мой ответ принял модератор, не "автор вопроса". Можно и отменить, я не против.  
Речь не об этом. Я не возражаю против развернутых ответов, но если они скопипасчены с инета, хотелось бы, во-первых, видеть источник, во-вторых, понять, действительно ли автор ответа" полагает, что это имеет отношение к вопросу и русскому языку и, в-третьих, какую-то оценку скопипасченного материала по сути. Это личное мнение, я не решаю за админов, но представление о "базе знаний" что-то подобное явно предполагает.

Comment: тур--это бык. а быками и башни в воде называют, те которые под мостами.  Русский язык это такая интересная штука, все на ассоциациях. Именно - что база знаний, реляционная.

Comment: @behemothus, какие у Вас есть аргументы, что одно из названий неправильное?

Answer (score 1):

> Ладью ... в шахматах профессионалы называют "тура"...

Никогда. Даже и не пытайтесь им это сказать.
Официально принятые названия фигур - Король, Ферзь, Ладья, Конь, Слон, Пешка.
Называть Ладью Турой или Ферзя Королевой могут только очень далекие от шахмат авторы.
Источник - Википедия.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B

Что касается этимологии самих названий, то
Ферзь (перс. فرزین‎ ferzin — визирь, советник.
Тура - вышка, обычно сборная. От франц. tour ж. " башня, тура".

=======

Русские

На территорию России шахматы приходили дважды: около IX века из Персии и уже в XVIII веке с Запада. Потому общепринятые русские названия фигур (за исключением короля) старинные и зачастую не отвечают облику.

В дореволюционной России встречались следующие названия фигур:
Ладья — тура, король — генерал, слон — офицер, ферзь — королева[6]:

```
… Туры могли сойти за рюмки, король — за самовар или генерала. Шишаки офицеров походили на электрические лампочки. Пару вороных и пару белых коней можно было запрячь в картонные пролетки и устроить биржу извозчиков или карусель. Особенно же были удобны обе королевы: блондинка и брюнетка. Каждая королева могла работать за ёлку, извозчика, китайскую пагоду, за цветочный горшок на подставке и за архиерея…

Лев Кассиль "Кондуит и Швамбрания"
```

В других языках

На Запад шахматы приходили разными путями, и обычно от арабов, а не от персов. Арабские фигуры часто были весьма схематичны, и их облик могли интерпретировать как угодно. Потому названия фигур бывают самые разные.

```
Король — титулы местных монархов (шах, малик, царь)
Ферзь — высший офицер (гетман, визирь), жена короля (королева, царица, дама).
Ладья — башня, тура, пушка, корабль, колесница, замок.
Слон — алфил (арабское название слона), бегун, гонец, охотник, стрелок, шут, епископ.
Конь — прыгун, рыцарь, всадник.
Пешка — солдат, крестьянин.
```

(Википедия), там же.